# Text-to-speech in PHP with Google Translate

Tags: php, html, text-to-speech, speech, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to convert **words** to **speech** ..

Untill now I have tried this:

```
<?php
 $text = "Hello this is a test for voice api of google";

// Name of the MP3 file generated using the MD5 hash
   $file  = md5($text);

// Save the MP3 file in this folder with the .mp3 extension 
   $file = "audio/" . $file .".mp3";
   if($file) {
     echo "created";
   } else {
     echo "not created";
   }

// If the MP3 file exists, do not create a new request
   if (!file_exists($file)) {
     $mp3 = file_get_contents(
        'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=' . $text);
     echo "hello";
     file_put_contents($file, $mp3);
   } else {
     echo "hii";
   }
?>
```

In my html file :

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="<?php echo $file; ?>" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

I am getting created hello and an audio player in output. But no file is played and neither it is created in the folder?

Comment: `$words` seems to be null ..

Comment: that was a typo.. See edit

Comment: Are you sure about that Google files are `type="audio/mp3"`? Maybe not.

Comment: Any idea on how to get ogg file as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. There is a problem with the url you try to access. It is broken ! You should have tried first.
   The new URL, that I found on the FF console is :

   http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&prev=input

   For the single word *Hello*. And you see that you have to specify the language, and the length of your text in **textlen**, even though it did work for all the sentences I tried without changing this var.
2. Another problem is that you have to urlencode() your text, or you will have a bug with accents and punctuation.
   So the line to download the MP3 becomes :

   ```
   // Language of the sentence
   $lang = "fr";
   $mp3 = file_get_contents(
   'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q='. urlencode($text) .'&tl='. $lang .'&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&prev=input');
   ```

So the complete code looks like :

```
<?php

    $text = "Bonjour, comment allez vous ?";
    // Yes French is a beautiful language.
    $lang = "fr";

    // MP3 filename generated using MD5 hash
    // Added things to prevent bug if you want same sentence in two different languages
    $file = md5($lang."?".urlencode($text));

    // Save MP3 file in folder with .mp3 extension 
    $file = "audio/" . $file . ".mp3";


    // Check folder exists, if not create it, else verify CHMOD
    if (!is_dir("audio/"))
        mkdir("audio/");
    else
        if (substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('audio/')), -4) != "0777")
            chmod("audio/", 0777);


    // If MP3 file exists do not create new request
    if (!file_exists($file))
    {
        // Download content
        $mp3 = file_get_contents(
        'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q='. urlencode($text) .'&tl='. $lang .'&total=1&idx=0&textlen=5&prev=input');
        file_put_contents($file, $mp3);
    }

?>
```

Comment: It works for me. But maybe try to add both solutions. Add the fopen() Inside the if(!file_exists) loop.

Comment: I updated the code, tell me it outputs *The file doesn't exist* ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: It can be that you did not create the /audio/ folder, or that you don't have the correct chmod, if you are on Unix. (I don't have this problem I am on Windows)

Comment: I added some changes, not sure about the CHMOD part, I put 0777 to be sure to have all access, but I think the good one would be 0755, but have a try on it first to see if it works.

Comment: Audio folder is there and that too with 777 permissions

Comment: Under PHP5 of course ? :) I ask you this because Idk from where it could come.

Comment: Oh my bad...Owner had to be www-data...Now the solution and api is working fine..Thanks a lot kube.

Comment: Works perfectly. How i can get translation in Male voice ?

Comment: I got the mp3 file created , but its not playing the text

Comment: I don't do PHP anymore, but I just tried to do some tts with https://github.com/zlargon/google-tts, which gives correct URL to retrieve the MP3, but it seems that it works better on the browser than on server-side. Maybe it comes from authentication or specific HTTP headers.

Answer (score 6):

I found it:

```
https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&q=ANYTHING_TEXT&tl=YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE
```

Important: `client=tw-ob`

`YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE` can be en,us,uk,vi etc.

Answer (score 3):

An improved version:

```
// ~~~ Credits to kube ~~~

    $text = "Hello this is a test for voice api of google";
    $text = urlencode($text);
    $lang = urldecode("en");
    $file  = "audio/" . md5($text) .".mp3";
       if (!file_exists($file) || filesize($file) == 0) {
         $mp3 = file_get_contents('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q='.$text.'&tl='.$lang.'&total=2&idx=0&textlen='.strlen($text).'&prev=input');
         if(file_put_contents($file, $mp3)){
            echo "Saved<br>";
         }else{
            echo "Wasn't able to save it !<br>";
         }
       } else {
         echo "Already exist<br>";
       }
```

Comment: I got Wasn't able to save it !

Comment: why total=2 in URL params?

Comment: @hRvoed I couldn't remember so I did some research, and according to this [resource](http://www.hung-truong.com/blog/2013/04/26/hacking-googles-text-to-speech-api/) it seems to specify the total chunks. Now I'm wondering if this answer really makes sense.

Comment: I researched as well just after. It appears this service is not free and we are not encouraged to use it. Input texts longer than 100 chars are splitted into chunks, thats where total and idx arguments jumps in. I gave up on Google and made an eSpeak powered text-to-speech website. The sound quality is not impressive but it works like a charm

Comment: How i can get translation in Male voice ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use this service for free.

> **Is there any free quota?**
>   No, the Google Translate API is only available as a paid service. Please see Pricing and Support for more details. However we do offer the Google Website Translator gadget, which will translate your website without charge.

Check [translate API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq)

More info about this unofficial way of use you can find on [Techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2009/12/14/the-unofficial-google-text-to-speech-api/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the simple code below. Just echo the code to get the result. In this code, there is no need to save a file or getting permission problems.

```
 echo "<iframe hidden src='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Welcome%20back%20".$jvm['firstname']."&tl=en&total=2&idx=0&textlen=5&prev=input'></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not creating because you forgot to create it , use below code for creating the file.

```
$file = "audio/".$file.".mp3";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Comment: It does not makes a file ... it outputs can't open file